# iOS 15.1.1 app UI keep breaking after few hour kept in background - React Native App

Tags: ios15

I have a similar issue in an iOS react-native app after iOS 15 upgrade but with not a crash.
Here the UI was totally broken, and the only way to fix it was to force restart the app.
If someone opens the app after 1 hour from the last time he/she opened it, the app skips the SplashScreen and after that nothing renders correctly. The positioning and order of components are wrong.
This happens only the first time after 1hour of app being closed.